# When I choose a new ordinance, how soon does it go into effect?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Does anyone know the details of the ordinance system? If I have one ordinance going, and cancel it to put a different one into effect, does the change happen immediately? The next day?

Answer (score 2):

They go into effect the day following your selection/payment for the new ordinance. Note that the "day" for Animal Crossing, for most purposes, starts at 6 AM, even though the date (of course) rolls over at midnight. This is noticeable if you're playing right before 6 AM as once the clock hits 6 a short cutscene will say "it's a new day" or similar and the game will save and continue as part of the "new day" process.

I believe Isabelle even tells you this as you change the ordinance.